# Responsive lightbox on background image

Tags: velo

I created a demo tour for my product, so I used an image as a background and on top of it lightbox.
So when I used Chrome, it looks great but on other browsers, the pointer does not point on the right object, the location is not the same.

Please open this URL on chrome, click "start tour" and then do the same on Edge

https://www.analytics-model.com/tutorial

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to this is bad.

The problem is also browser independent as the window size of the browser is what misaligns the overlay-elements of your tour. 
It's simply bad responsive design to other window sizes.

First, don't use an backdrop-image, also not for a demo.
Reason is, the overlay element needs to be relative to the actual HTML element it's revering to and this can't (easily) be done with an image.

To anchor an element to another one, in this case, a toolbar symbol to the overlay explainer element, you can use the css position property in conjunction with top, bottom, left and right properties.

The anchor element should have the css property "position: relative" and this anchor element has the explainer overlay in it's inner HTML.
The overlay has "position: absolute;" as it's css property and with top, bottom, left and right you then can position it however you please, relative to the anchor element.

In simplified code this looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="anchor" >
  Account
  <div class="explainer">
    This explains everything about your account.
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.anchor {
  position: relative
}

.explainer {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Working example demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krischna_Gabriel/uwzxqfer/191/